# How to get the list of installed apps from  a launch daemon

Tags: cocoa

How to get the path of installed apps when querying from a  root privileges app( launch daemon),I have used LSCopyApplicationURLsForURl ,it is not working from a launch daemon app .

Any alternate solutions,please help me.

Regards,
Akbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mdfind` command provides the information you're looking for:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemContentTypeTree == "com.apple.application"c' | sort
```

I'm aware the question is dated, but my answer might be in time for someone else :)